# upgrade Rails 4.1.7 from 3.2.17 ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rake

After update gems like:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.7'
```

bundle update. works ok, but when execute `rake rails:update`

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity
rvm_path/gems/active_presenter-3.2.2/lib/active_presenter/base.rb:8:in `<class:Base>'
rvm_path/gems/active_presenter-3.2.2/lib/active_presenter/base.rb:4:in `<module:ActivePresenter>'
rvm_path/gems/active_presenter-3.2.2/lib/active_presenter/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
rvm_path/gems/active_presenter-3.2.2/lib/active_presenter.rb:3:in `require'
rvm_path/gems/active_presenter-3.2.2/lib/active_presenter.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
rvm_path/gems/active_presenter-3.2.2/lib/active_presenter.rb:3:in `each'
rvm_path/gems/active_presenter-3.2.2/lib/active_presenter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
rvm_path/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
rvm_path/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
rvm_path/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
rvm_path/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
rvm_path/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
rvm_path/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
rvm_path/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
app_path/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
app_path/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**bundle show**

```
  * actionmailer (4.1.7)
  * actionpack (4.1.7)
  * actionview (4.1.7)
  * active_presenter (3.2.2)
  * activemodel (4.1.7)
  * activerecord (4.1.7)
  * activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
  * activeresource (4.0.0)
  * activesupport (4.1.7)
  * acts-as-taggable-on (3.4.2)
  * acts_as_list (0.1.9)
  * addressable (2.3.6)
  * after_party (1.2)
  * airbrake (3.1.12)
  * amoeba (2.0.0)
  * annotate (2.5.0)
  * apartment (0.24.3)
  * arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
  * arrayfields (4.9.2)
  * awesome_nested_set (2.1.6)
  * awesome_print (1.2.0)
  * axlsx (2.0.1)
  * bcrypt (3.1.9)
  * beesor-docs (0.9.8)
  * beesor-jquery-render-rails (0.0.17)
  * best_in_place (3.0.0)
  * better_errors (1.0.1)
  * binding_of_caller (0.7.1)
  * bluff (0.1.0)
  * bootstrap-sass (3.0.3.0)
  * bootstrap-switch-rails (3.0.0)
  * bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails (3.1.3)
  * bootstrap_sortable_rails (1.8.0)
  * brakeman (2.4.3)
  * builder (3.2.2)
  * bullet (4.6.0)
  * bundler (1.6.2)
  * cane (2.6.2)
  * capybara (2.4.4)
  * capybara-webkit (1.3.1)
  * celluloid (0.16.0)
  * chosen-rails (1.0.2)
  * chronic (0.10.2)
  * chunky_png (1.3.3)
  * churn (0.0.35)
  * ci_reporter (1.9.0)
  * code_analyzer (0.4.5)
  * code_metrics (0.1.3)
  * coderay (1.1.0)
  * coffee-rails (4.1.0)
  * coffee-script (2.3.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
  * colored (1.2)
  * colorize (0.7.3)
  * compass (0.12.3)
  * compass-rails (1.1.3)
  * connection_pool (2.0.0)
  * cucumber (1.3.7)
  * cucumber-rails (1.4.0)
  * database_cleaner (1.0.1)
  * debug_inspector (0.0.2)
  * devise (3.4.1)
  * devise_security_extension (0.8.0)
  * diff-lcs (1.2.5)
  * dotenv (0.10.0)
  * dotenv-rails (0.10.0)
  * draper (1.2.1)
  * easy_translate (0.5.0)
  * enumerize (0.7.0)
  * enumerize-matchers (0.0.1)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (2.2.2)
  * factory_girl (4.2.0)
  * factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
  * faker (1.3.0)
  * fastercsv (1.5.5)
  * fattr (2.2.2)
  * ffi (1.9.6)
  * flay (2.5.0)
  * flog (4.3.0)
  * font-awesome-rails (4.1.0.0)
  * friendly_id (4.0.10)
  * fssm (0.2.10)
  * gherkin (2.12.2)
  * globalize (4.0.2)
  * globalize-accessors (0.1.3)
  * gon (4.1.0)
  * haml (4.0.3)
  * haml-rails (0.5.3)
  * hammerjs_rails (1.1.3.1)
  * highline (1.6.21)
  * hike (1.2.3)
  * hirb (0.7.2)
  * hitimes (1.2.2)
  * htmlentities (4.3.2)
  * i18n (0.6.11)
  * i18n-js (2.1.2)
  * i18n-tasks (0.5.1)
  * icheck-rails (0.9.0.2)
  * infinitescrolling-rails (0.3.0)
  * jquery-cookie-rails (1.3.1.1)
  * jquery-rails (3.0.4)
  * json (1.8.1)
  * json_pure (1.8.1)
  * json_spec (1.1.1)
  * kaminari (0.14.1)
  * kgio (2.9.2)
  * konacha (3.0.0)
  * language_list (1.0.0)
  * launchy (2.3.0)
  * libnotify (0.8.4)
  * lic_provider (0.2.2)
  * listen (1.0.3)
  * lol_dba (1.6.0)
  * mail (2.6.3)
  * main (6.1.0)
  * map (6.5.5)
  * memory_test_fix (1.2.2)
  * metric_fu (4.4.1)
  * metric_fu-Saikuro (1.1.3)
  * mime-types (2.4.3)
  * mini_portile (0.6.1)
  * minitest (5.4.3)
  * momentjs-rails (2.8.3)
  * multi_json (1.7.9)
  * multi_test (0.1.1)
  * netrc (0.8.0)
  * nicescroll-rails (3.5.4.1)
  * nokogiri (1.6.4.1)
  * orm_adapter (0.5.0)
  * parallel (1.3.3)
  * pg (0.17.1)
  * pjax_rails (0.3.4)
  * pnotify-rails (1.2.2)
  * protected_attributes (1.0.8)
  * public_activity (1.4.1)
  * quiet_assets (1.0.2)
  * rabl (0.8.6)
  * rack (1.5.2)
  * rack-mini-profiler (0.1.31)
  * rack-protection (1.5.3)
  * rack-test (0.6.2)
  * rails (4.1.7)
  * rails-dev-tweaks (1.2.0)
  * rails-observers (0.1.2)
  * rails-timeago (2.11.1)
  * rails_best_practices (1.15.4)
  * railties (4.1.7)
  * rainbow (2.0.0)
  * raindrops (0.13.0)
  * rake (10.3.2)
  * rb-fchange (0.0.6)
  * rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
  * rb-inotify (0.9.0)
  * rb-kqueue (0.2.3)
  * redcard (1.1.0)
  * redcarpet (3.1.1)
  * redis (3.0.7)
  * redis-actionpack (4.0.0)
  * redis-activesupport (4.0.0)
  * redis-namespace (1.4.1)
  * redis-rack (1.5.0)
  * redis-rails (4.0.0)
  * redis-session-store (0.8.0)
  * redis-store (1.1.4)
  * reek (1.3.8)
  * request_store (1.0.8)
  * require_all (1.3.2)
  * responders (1.0.0)
  * rest-client (1.7.2)
  * roodi (3.3.1)
  * rspec (2.13.0)
  * rspec-core (2.13.1)
  * rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
  * rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
  * rspec-rails (2.13.2)
  * ruby-progressbar (1.7.0)
  * ruby2ruby (2.0.8)
  * ruby_parser (3.4.1)
  * rubyzip (1.0.0)
  * sass (3.2.14)
  * sass-rails (4.0.3)
  * scrollToFixed_rails (1.0.0)
  * seedbank (0.3.0)
  * sexp_processor (4.4.4)
  * shoulda-matchers (2.2.0)
  * sidekiq (3.0.0)
  * simple_form (3.0.2)
  * simplecov (0.7.1)
  * simplecov-html (0.7.1)
  * simplecov-rcov (0.2.3)
  * sinatra (1.4.3)
  * six (0.2.0)
  * slim (2.1.0)
  * slop (3.6.0)
  * spring (1.1.2)
  * spring-commands-cucumber (1.0.1)
  * spring-commands-rspec (1.0.1)
  * sprockets (2.11.0)
  * sprockets-rails (2.2.0)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.8)
  * temple (0.6.10)
  * term-ansicolor (1.3.0)
  * terminal-table (1.4.5)
  * the_sortable_tree (2.4.0)
  * thor (0.19.1)
  * thread (0.1.4)
  * thread_safe (0.3.4)
  * tilt (1.4.1)
  * timers (4.0.1)
  * tins (1.3.3)
  * tzinfo (1.2.2)
  * uglifier (2.2.1)
  * unicorn (4.8.3)
  * unicorn-worker-killer (0.4.2)
  * uniform_notifier (1.6.2)
  * validates_overlap (0.2.0)
  * warden (1.2.3)
  * xpath (2.0.0)
```

Comment: Essentially it would appear active presenter isn't compatible with rails 3.  It's not been updated in about 2 years, so I don't think it's going to be unless you want to fork it and update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActivePresenter` is not compatible with Rails 4.x.

`ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity` has been dropped with Rails 3.2.x. Since Rails 4.x [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) are used.

ps. I would suggest upgrade step by step, I mean from 3.2 to 4.0 and then from 4.0 to 4.1.